# How to remove Resize indicator (gray line in right bottom corner) from form?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

Game window is declared with this code:

```
Form gameWindow;
...

gameWindow = new Form();
gameWindow.ShowDialog();
```

How to remove resize indicator? I don't want to disable resizing, just to remove this gray icon

[image]

Comment: Your English isn't the problem.  I'd prefer that you paste your image into the question rather than providing an off-site link.  Including code that caused the issue would be even better.

Comment: FormBorderStyle must be changed, if Sizeable then you will see that gray thing, otherwise that gray thing is gone

Comment: I can't add image directly, it says that I haven't got enough reputation points.

And I don't want to disable resizing, just to remove this gray icon.
When I'm creating Windows Form App, I can resize window, but form is empty.

Comment: @duffymo IIRC new users *can't* paste images into questions.

Comment: Didn't know.  It's been a long time since I was a new user.  Feature might not have existed when I started here.

Comment: @duffymo Yeah, been a while for me too.

Comment: I flag this question for reopen, because duplicate target is incorrect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change only `SizeGripStyle` to hidden and keep form resizeable

```
gameWindow.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the form border style to FixedSingle.

On the propieties of the form:

[image]

Comment: When I'll do it, Form will be unresizable.

Comment: Indeed, ASh solution will do it